# jQuery - How to print class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This my example of my situation,I have a menu that using same class and want to print out name of class.

```
<a href="#" class="top" onClick="test()">Home</a> 
<a href="#" class="top" onClick="test()">Profile</a> 
<a href="#" class="top" onClick="test()">background</a>
```

Here I have tried to create a function but can't work. 
The expected result will show "top selected"

```
function test(){
 var getClass = $(this).find('.top'); 
 if(getClass=='top'){
   alert(getClass +'selected');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="top" onClick="test(this)">Home</a>
```

and then...

```
    function test(el){
      var className = $(el).attr('class');
      console.log(className);
   }
```

Comment: Yes it is using the same `.attr` jQuery function to get the class name, I just made it reusable by getting the class of the clicked element instead of a hard coded `.top`, which is the class.

Answer (score 2):

```
var className = $('.top').attr('class');
console.log(className);
```

this should work

Comment: getting the `class` value by using the `class` as a selector? seems a bit silly lol

Comment: look to he's if statment :) if(getClass=='top')

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="top" onClick="test()">Home</a> 
<a href="#" class="top" onClick="test()">Profile</a> 
<a href="#" class="top" onClick="test()">background</a>

<p></p>

var className = $( 'a' ).attr( 'class' );
$( 'p' ).text(className);
// console.log(className);
```